# Android RemoteViews setViewVisibility not working

Tags: android, visibility, android-appwidget, remoteview, homescreen

I'm dealing with a problem in a home screen widget, and trying to disply or hide buttons according to network availability and state, so if connected, buttons will be displayed and content loaded, and if not connected this will hide all content and display message. The problem is that remoteViews.setViewVisibility is not working as expected in all cases. Here is my code :

```
public class WidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {
    ArrayList<WidgetOffer> widgetOffers;

public static Cursor cOffer;
public static RemoteViews remoteViews;
public static String TAG  = "WidgetProvider";
public static String NEXT_OFFER_ACTION = "NEXT_OFFER_ACTION";
public static String PREV_OFFER_ACTION = "PREV_OFFER_ACTION";
public static String BOOK_OFFER_ACTION = "BOOK_OFFER_ACTION";

@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);
    if(isOnline(context)){
        Log.v(TAG, "On Update Connected");
        remoteViews.setViewVisibility(R.id.tvConnError, View.INVISIBLE);
        loadWidgetOffers lwo = new loadWidgetOffers(context);
        lwo.execute();
    }else{
        Log.v(TAG, "On Update Disconnected");

        remoteViews.setViewVisibility(R.id.right_arrow, View.INVISIBLE);
        remoteViews.setViewVisibility(R.id.left_arrow, View.INVISIBLE);
        remoteViews.setViewVisibility(R.id.btnBook, View.INVISIBLE);
        remoteViews.setViewVisibility(R.id.pbLoading, View.INVISIBLE);
        remoteViews.setViewVisibility(R.id.tvConnError, View.VISIBLE);

    }
    pushWidgetUpdate(context, remoteViews);
}

@Override
public void onDeleted(Context context, int[] appWidgetIds){
    Toast.makeText(context, "Widget Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    super.onDeleted(context, appWidgetIds);
}

@Override
public void onDisabled(Context context){
    Toast.makeText(context, "Widget Disabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    super.onDisabled(context);
}

@Override
public void onEnabled(Context context){
    Toast.makeText(context, "Widget Enabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Log.v(TAG, "On Enabled");

    super.onEnabled(context);
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    super.onReceive(context, intent);


}

public static PendingIntent NextOfferPI(Context context) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, TraveltodoWidgetIntentReceiver.class);
    intent.setAction(NEXT_OFFER_ACTION);
    return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
}

public static PendingIntent PrevOfferPI(Context context) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, TraveltodoWidgetIntentReceiver.class);
    intent.setAction(PREV_OFFER_ACTION);
    return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
}

public static PendingIntent BookOfferPI(Context context) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, TraveltodoWidgetIntentReceiver.class);
    intent.setAction(BOOK_OFFER_ACTION);
    return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
}

public static void pushWidgetUpdate(Context context, RemoteViews remoteviews) {
    ComponentName myWidget = new ComponentName(context, TraveltodoWidgetProvider.class);
    AppWidgetManager manager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
    manager.updateAppWidget(myWidget, remoteviews); 
    Log.v(TAG, "pushWidgetUpdate");
}

private class loadWidgetOffers extends AsyncTask<String, String, Boolean>{
    private Context c;

    public loadWidgetOffers(Context context){
        c = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute(){
        Log.i("Parse Widget Offers", "Pre");
        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(c);
        db.resetTables();
        db.close();
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
        Log.i("Parse Widget Offers", "Processing");
        try {
            widgetOffers= new ArrayList<WidgetOffer>();
            WidgetOfferParser wop = new WidgetOfferParser("http://server_name/newsClient2.xml");
            widgetOffers = wop.Parse();
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {

        if(success == true){
            Log.i(TAG, "Post Execute Success");
            SharedPreferences prefs = c.getSharedPreferences("com.package", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(c);
            Boolean offersExist = false;

            if(widgetOffers.size() > 0){
                prefs.edit().putInt("TotalOffers", widgetOffers.size()).commit();
                offersExist = true;
                for(int i = 0; i < widgetOffers.size(); i++){
                    WidgetOffer wo = widgetOffers.get(i);
                    db.addOffer(wo.getTitle(), wo.getDescription(), wo.getDetail(), wo.getOldPrice(), wo.getNewPrice(), wo.getIdOffer());
                }
            }

            if (offersExist){
                Log.i(TAG, "Post Execute Success With Offers");
                cOffer = db.getOffer("1");

                //RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(c.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);
                remoteViews.setViewVisibility(R.id.tvConnError, View.INVISIBLE);
                remoteViews.setViewVisibility(R.id.pbLoading, View.INVISIBLE);

                remoteViews.setViewVisibility(R.id.right_arrow, View.VISIBLE);
                remoteViews.setViewVisibility(R.id.left_arrow, View.VISIBLE);
                remoteViews.setViewVisibility(R.id.btnBook, View.VISIBLE);

                remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.right_arrow, TraveltodoWidgetProvider.NextOfferPI(c));
                remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.left_arrow, TraveltodoWidgetProvider.PrevOfferPI(c));

                remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.tvWidTitle, cOffer.getString(1));
                remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.tvWidDescription, cOffer.getString(2));
                remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.tvPrice1, cOffer.getString(5));

                String cl = "some url";
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                myIntent.setData(Uri.parse(cl));
                PendingIntent pendIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(c, 0, myIntent,0);
                remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.btnBook, pendIntent);

                prefs.edit().putInt("CurrentOffer", 1).commit();
                prefs.edit().putString("CurrentLink", cl).commit();

                pushWidgetUpdate(c,remoteViews);
            }
        }else{
            Log.i(TAG, "Post Execute Fail");
            remoteViews.setViewVisibility(R.id.pbLoading, View.INVISIBLE);
            Toast.makeText(c, "Pas de connexion", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            pushWidgetUpdate(c,remoteViews);
        }


    }
}

private boolean isOnline(Context c) {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) c.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

any help would be appreciated
Thanks

Comment: You need to be more specific. "is not working as expected in all cases" could mean pretty much anything.

Comment: Can you please share the solution cause I am having the same problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If "is not working as expected in all cases" means "elements become invisible but they still use space", try `View.Gone` instead of `View.Invisible`:

```
remoteViews.setViewVisibility(R.id.right_arrow, View.GONE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
remoteViews.setInt(R.id.close, "setVisibility", View.GONE);
```

Comment: `setViewVisibility` is a wrapper for `setInt`